# Trying to drop NaN indexed row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python 2.7.3 and Pandas version 0.12.0.

I want to drop the row with the NaN index so that I only have valid site_id values.

```
print df.head()
            special_name
site_id
NaN          Banana
OMG          Apple

df.drop(df.index[0])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

If I try dropping a range, like this:

```
df.drop(df.index[0:1])
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'special_name'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found that the easiest way is to reset the index, drop the NaNs, and then reset the index again.

```
In [26]: dfA.reset_index()
Out[26]: 
  index special_name
0   NaN        Apple
1   OMG       Banana

In [30]: df = dfA.reset_index().dropna().set_index('index')

In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
      special_name
index             
OMG         Banana
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.index.dropna()]` works in recent versions.

Comment: This is going to drop rows that have a null value in ANY row, not just the index. I'd recommend using @timdiels's answer instead.

Answer (score 58):

With pandas version >= 0.20.0 you can:

```py
df = df[df.index.notnull()]
```

With older versions:

```
df = df[pandas.notnull(df.index)]
```

To break it down:

`notnull` generates a boolean mask, e.g. `[False, False, True]`, where True denotes the value at the corresponding position is null (`numpy.nan` or `None`). We then select the rows whose index corresponds to a true value in the mask by using `df[boolean_mask]`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be notnull() instead of isnull()?

Comment: Is same as `df[df.index.notnull()]`

Comment: Thanks to Pietro Battiston and Zero for the latest best answer.

Comment: This is indeed the cleanest and most concise answer. I'd just add that it needs to be assigned back to the original `df` or to another dataframe for the null indices to be truly considered dropped from the dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers worked 100% for me. Here's what worked:

```
In [26]: print df
Out[26]:            
          site_id      special_name
0         OMG          Apple
1         NaN          Banana
2         RLY          Orange


In [27]: df.dropna(inplace=True)
Out[27]:            
          site_id      special_name
0         OMG          Apple
2         RLY          Orange

In [28]: df.reset_index(inplace=True)
Out[28]:            
          index     site_id      special_name
0         0         OMG          Apple
1         2         RLY          Orange

In [29]: df.drop('index', axis='columns', inplace=True)
Out[29]:             
          site_id      special_name
0         OMG          Apple
1         RLY          Orange
```

Answer (score 5):

As of `pandas` 0.19, `Index`es do have a `.notnull()` method, so the answer by **timdiels** can be simplified to:

```
df[df.index.notnull()]
```

which I think is (currently) the simplest you can get.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: the following probably only applies to `MultiIndex`s, and is in any case obsoleted by the new `df.index.isnull()` function (see other answers). I'll leave this answer just for historical interest.*

For people who come to this now, one can do this directly without reindexing by relying on the fact that NaNs in the index will be represented with the label `-1`. So:

```
df = dfA[dfA.index.labels!=-1]
```

Even better, in Pandas>0.16.1, one can use drop() to do this inplace without copying:

```
dfA.drop(labels=[-1], level='index', inplace=True)
```

NB: It's a bit misleading that the index level is called 'index': it would usually be something more use-specific like 'date' or 'experimental_run'..

Comment: Doesn't work in pandas 0.17.0. `Index` has no `labels` attribute, The suggested drop leads to `AssertionError: axis must be a MultiIndex`.

Comment: What if my index has both `NaN` values and `-1` values?

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol The code above references the `labels` of the index, not the index directly: `NaN` values in the index are represented by `-1` in the `labels`. I don't believe the `labels` attribute can ever contain `NaN`.

Comment: @timdiels thanks for comment - could well be the case that this doesn't work without MultiIndex. In any case I think it's an obsoleted answer now that pandas has a `df.index.notnull()` function. I'll leave it stand for historical interest.

Answer (score 2):

Tested this to be working :

`df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

`df.drop(df[df['index'].isnull()].index, inplace=True)`

---

### How I checked the above

Replicated the table in the original question using 
`df=pd.DataFrame(data=['Banana', 'Apple'], index=[np.nan, 'OMG'],columns=['Special_name'])`

then input the above two code lines- which I try to explain in human language below:

- 1st line resets the index to integers, and the NaN is now in a column named after the original name of the index ('index' in the example above as there was no name specified) - pandas does this automatically with the reset_index() command.
- 2nd line from innermost brackets: `df[df['index'].isnull()]` filters rows for which column named 'index' shows 'NaN' values using isnull() command. `.index` is used to pass an unambiguous index object pointing to all 'index'=NaN rows to the `df.drop(` in the outermost part of the expression.

nb: tested the above command to work on multiple NaN values in a column

Using Python 3.5.1 , Pandas 0.17.1 via Anaconda package 32bits

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [4]: df.query('index == index')
Out[4]: 
        special_name
site_id             
OMG            Apple
```

This works as NaN when compared to itself returns *False*:

```
In [5]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[5]: False
```

Comment: Good alternative specially when you're planning to do multiple chained transformations to a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```
df[df.index.notna()]
```